# Vuetify components not linking properly in NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm attempting to use the Vuetify [`v-list`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/) component in NuxtJS however when I deploy my app the list is not reactive at all (no hover effect, no linking).

The documentation for NuxtJS says all internal page links must use the `<NuxtLink>` component, but how is this possible when using pre-built components?

The NuxtLink component adds undesired styling. I'm assuming I'll need to hack away at the CSS to make it not do this?

```html
<v-list>
    <v-list-item to="/some/endpoint">
       <!-- content -->
    </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

- Linking not working after being built
- Component not reactive -- no hover effect (Assume because link is not registering).

Comment: `however when I deploy my app`, does it mean that it works locally? Also, did you checked the [`nuxt` prop](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item/#props-nuxt)? Adding it should fix most of the issue. Then, if you want to have a different look, CSS is indeed the way to go.

Comment: Thanks again! Was not even aware vuetify had this as a prob, didn't even consider it. I think that will then solve my issue. Please feel free to submit answers for both of questions, otherwise I'll come through later and post what worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this should work

```html
<v-list-item nuxt to="/some/endpoint">
```

As told in [the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item/#props-nuxt)

> Specifies the link is a nuxt-link. For use with the nuxt framework.

If you want to style the specific nuxt links, you can check [this part](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/nuxt-components#linkactiveclass) of the documentation. Otherwise, the rest is probably Vuetify specific than can be overwritten with regular CSS.